# Swift : Searchbar localizedCaseInsensitiveContainsString is not working or error

Tags: xcode, swift, searchbar

Trying to search using `localizedCaseInsensitiveContainsString` and getting following error message.

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString
>   localizedCaseInsensitiveContainsString:]: unrecognized selector sent
>   to instance 0x1702297a0'

```
var guests = [Guest]() 
var guestresults = [Guest]()

func searchBar(searchBar: UISearchBar!, textDidChange searchText: String!) {
    guestresults = guests.filter {
        ($0.firstname as NSString).localizedCaseInsensitiveContainsString("\(searchText)")
        //($0.firstname as NSString) == searchText
    } 
}
```

But when i use compare is working

```
($0.firstname as NSString) == searchText
```

Its xcode 6 beta 4
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`localizedCaseInsensitiveContainsString` was introduced in iOS 8/OS X 10.10,
therefore

```
(str1 as NSString).localizedCaseInsensitiveContainsString(str2)
```

crashes with the "unrecognised selector" exception on iOS 7. But you can replace it
with the equivalent

```
(str1 as NSString).rangeOfString(str2, options: .CaseInsensitiveSearch).location != NSNotFound
```

which works back to iOS 2.0.